# Why do I not get labels rendered from CharField when using DJANGO formset

Tags: html, django, label, formset

I have a form with 2 CharFields. Both have label="xyz".
If I use this form in a formset, the lables are not shown in the HTML

I have tried looking at the rendered HTML and the label is missing. I have tried just a form and that works.

Forms:

```py
class WindingVoltsSpecifier(forms.Form):
    winding_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label="Winding name")
    voltages = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label="Voltages")
```

View:

```py
def add_mains_transformer_primary_configs(request):
    # Add a new config

    # Create the formset, specifying the form and formset we want to use.
    # From https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html
    VoltsSpecifierFormSet = formset_factory(WindingVoltsSpecifier)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass

    else:


        mt_config_form = MainsTransformerConfiguration()
        volts_formset = VoltsSpecifierFormSet()

        context = {
            'mt_config_form' : mt_config_form,
            'volts_formset' : volts_formset,

        }

    return render(request, 'designer/mains_configs.html', context)
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'designer/base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}configuration{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<h1>Configuration</h1>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}


    {{ mt_config_form|crispy }}

    {{ volts_formset.management_form|crispy }}

    {% for volts_form in volts_formset %}

        <table>
        {% for form in volts_form %}
        {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    <table>
    <!--<div class="volts-formset">
        {{ volts_form.winding_name }}
        {{ volts_form.voltages }}
    </div>
    -->
    {% endfor %}

    {% if volts_formset.non_form_errors %}
        {% for error in volts_formset.non_form_errors %}
            {{ error|escape }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}




    <input type="submit" value="Update Profile" class="button" />
</form>

<script>
    $('.volts-formset').formset({
        addText: 'add winding',
        deleteText: 'remove'
    });
</script>



{% endblock %}
```

I would expect the label to be beside the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels are not rendered with fields, you will have to do a `{{ FIELD.label_tag }}`.

It will be something like this:

```
<table>
    {% for field in volts_form %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
<table>
```

More info: [Looping over the forms fields - Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#s-looping-over-the-form-s-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution to works!

```
{% for field in volts_forms %}
    {{ field.name}} <!-- label name -->
    {{ field }}<!-- ex. input -->
{% endfor %}
```